# How do sort Templatefield in spgridview?

Tags: 2010, web-part, spgridview

I  have a spgrid with BoundField. I set allowsort to true.

I bind datasource.

but when i click in header dont sort?!

```
 DataTable table = new DataTable();

        table.Columns.Add("Name");
        table.Columns.Add("ID");
        table.Columns.Add("User");
        table.Columns.Add("UName");
        DataRow dr = table.NewRow();
            dr["Name"] = item["Title"];
            dr["ID"] = item["ID"];
  table.Rows.Add(dr);
  GridView.DataSource = table;
  GridView.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried any of these examples (sorting must be "implemented" when using a DataSource other than the a List/View or result of SPQuery)?

1. http://www.threewill.com/2010/08/the-great-and-powerful-spgridview/
2. http://sharethefrustration.blogspot.com/2010/02/spgridview-webpart-with-multiple-filter.html

Answer (score 1):

Dont forget to set the 'onSorting' = 'your_event_handler', and give each sortable column a 'sortExpression'.

I also advise declaring the DataTable as a global variable so you can cache the data for sorting during the event. *Beware the e.SortDirection stays 'Ascending' unless you deal with it, so instead I use a work around and track the current column name & direction to do it myself.

```
  private static Datatable table;
  private static string sort_col;
  private static string sort_dir;
  private void yourPreviousFunction() { table = new DataTable() etc..}

  public void your_even_handler(object sender, GridViewSortingEventArgs e)
  {
       if(e.sortingExpression.ToString() != sort_col || sort_dir=="Desc")
       {
             sort_col=e.sortingExpression;
             sort_dir="ASC";
        }
        else sort_dir="Desc";

        table.DefaultView.sort = sort_col+" "+sort_dir;
        GridView.DataSource= table;
        GridView.DataBind();
   }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: And for a multi-column sort..  Datatable.DefaultView.sort ="col1 Dir, col2 Dir"